# Calculate how many clients ordered less than one month after their first, second, ... order

Tags: mysql, database

Let's start with my tables (simplified for my question) (using MySQL):

```
client :
+----------+----------------------+
| idClient |    insctiptionDate   |
+----------+----------------------+
|     1    | 2017-07-31 14:51:22  |
+----------+----------------------+
|     2    | 2017-07-18 08:25:36  |
+----------+----------------------+

delivery :
+----------+----------------------+
| fkClient |         date         |
+----------+----------------------+
|     1    | 2017-07-31 14:51:22  |
+----------+----------------------+
|     1    | 2017-08-10 13:30:22  |
+----------+----------------------+
|     2    | 2017-07-18 08:25:36  |
+----------+----------------------+
```

The inscriptionDate column is equal to the date of the first delivery for each client.

I need to know how many clients ordered a second time in the 28 firsts days after their first command.

So far, I have this :

```
SELECT
  YEARWEEK(tmp.first) AS Week,
  COUNT(tmp.id) AS Total  
FROM (
  SELECT
    c.idClient as id,
    (SELECT
        MIN(d.date)
     FROM delivery d
     WHERE c.idClient = d.fkClient 
    ) AS first
  FROM client c
  ORDER BY first ASC
  ) AS tmp
WHERE (
  SELECT
    MIN(d.date)
  FROM delivery d
  WHERE tmp.id = d.fkClient
  AND d.date != tmp.first
  AND DATEDIFF(d.date, tmp.first) <= 28
  ) IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY YEARWEEK(first)
 ORDER BY YEARWEEK(first);
```

I first get the first delivery for all my clients, then I count how many of them ordered a second time in the next 28 days.

My problems are:

- I'm not sure this is the most elegant solution or even if this really work so I'm open to any suggestion here
- I am limited to only one SELECT to do this (I am using the SQL mode
  of Chartio to visualize the results)
- I need to expand this to also know how many clients order after their
  second delivery, their third, ... and I am really stuck here!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you need the second time date, 3rd time... or just how many time they ordered ?

Comment: I just need to know how many client ordered after their first, after their second time, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've decided to use a python script to calculate those kind of values.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but i think you should do something like that :

```
SELECT IdClient, SUM(NumberCommand)
FROM
(   SELECT
        SUM(
            CASE 
                WHEN 
                    @previousId = d.fkClient
                    THEN
                    CASE
                        WHEN @prevDate <>d.date
                            AND DATEDIFF(d.date,@prevDate)<=28
                        THEN 1 
                        ELSE 0
                    END
                ELSE
                    1
        ) AS NumberCommand,

        (@previousId := d.fkClient) as IdClient,
        (@prevDate := d.date) as DateDelivery
    FROM 
    delivery d,
    INNER JOIN (SELECT @prevDate := inscriptionDate, idClient FROM client) b
        ON b.idClient = d.fkClient
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @previousId:=0) a
    GROUP BY IdClient, DateDelivery
    ORDER BY IdClient, d.date) C 
GROUP BY IdClient
```